# How to use mysql where condition in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to write this query in magento

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = 1 AND name = 'abc';
```

So far I tried this:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$table = $this->getMainTable();
$where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("user_id = ?", 1);
       $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($table,array('firstname'))->where($where);
       $data = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
       print_r($data);
```

I don't know how to combine two where conditions and print all rows that satisfy particular condition.

Comment: $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($table,array('firstname'))->where("user_id = 1 AND name = 'abc'");  try with this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$table = $this->getMainTable();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_id = 1 AND name = 'abc' ";
$res = $connection->fetchOne($sql);
print_r($res);
```

[For more see here.](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

**[Edit]**

As per your comment you can use like:

```
 $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
 ->from($this->getTable('api/session'), 'user_id')
 ->where('user_id = ?', $user->getId())
  ->where('sessid = ?', $user->getSessid());
$data = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: This works I know but I need using magento sql operation not wiyh pure sql query

Comment: @Birju updated the answer please check

Comment: cool this multiple where condition works, but what I need is I want to print all columns as in case 'select * from table name' we get whole columns that satisfy where condition, but in your case I get only user_id as u have given this statement ->from($this->getTable('api/session'), 'user_id'). Can u help me more please.

Comment: @Birju you have to use `fetchAll()` instead `fetchRow()` or `fetchOne()`

Comment: Can we use OR condition in where ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal Yes you can

Comment: Using "orWhere" ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal like MySQL